# C# Solution gets unspecified error when trying to publish

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, excel-interop

I have these imports:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V108.Runtime;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V108.Audits;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V108.Memory;
using System.Threading;
```

This is the first time i'm trying to publish a self-contained program so that others within my company can use it by just clicking the exe.
The only error i am getting is:

> Publish has encountered an error.
> Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9E64.tmp""

The log file says:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
```

Comment: `A diagnostic log has been written to the following location: "C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9E64.tmp""` Care to share? ;)

Comment: Updated now, thought it said basically the same thing at first

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by looking in the build output now.

It was because of a lot of outdated NuGet packages, got fixed immediately when i updated/downloaded them.